# Duplicate entries when trying to retrieve data from a tree structure

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 tables :

`obs_structure(id, auteur_cre, dt_cre, dt_modif, description, auteur_modif, structid, tag)`

and

`obs_structure_element(id, auteur_cre, dt_cre, dt_modif, description, auteur_modif, optional, repetitive, suite, tag, terminal, parent_id, type_id)`

There is a link between this tables like : `obs_structure_element.parent_id = obs_structure.id` and `obs_structure_element.type_id = obs_structure.id`.

I would like to give a particular `obs_structure.structid` and retrieve all the children of this structure. I've found a piece of code and adapted to my use case :

```
    select * from 
(
      select 
          os.id as structure_id,
          os.description as structure_descr,
          os.structid as structid,
          os.tag as structure_tag,
          ose.id as element_id,
          ose.description as element_descr,
          ose.optional as element_optional,
          ose.repetitive as element_repetitif,
          ose.suite as elements_suite,
          ose.tag as element_tag,
          ose.terminal as element_terminal,
          ose.parent_id as element_parent_id,
          ose.type_id as element_type_id
      from obs_structure os 
      right join OBS_STRUCTURE_ELEMENT ose
      on os.ID = ose.TYPE_ID
)
start with element_parent_id = (select os.id from obs_structure os where os.structid = 'BDP')
connect by PRIOR element_type_id = element_parent_id
order by element_parent_id, elements_suite;
```

This gives me all the children of the structure that i've chosen. The problem is that for a reason that I can't understand I have duplicate entries (see picture). 
[image]

PS: My database is oracle

Thank you for your help :)

**EDIT:** 
if we replace the first select by `select count(*)` we have 421 entries but if we replace by `select count(distinct(element_id))` we have 260 entries that seems to be the right number of entries that I should have....

**EDIT2:** 
Seems that my problem can be solved this way :

```
select distinct structure_id,structure_descr,structid,structure_tag,element_id,element_descr,elements_suite,element_tag,element_parent_id,element_type_id from 
(
    select
    os.id as structure_id,
    os.description as structure_descr,
    os.structid as structid,
    os.tag as structure_tag,
    ose.id as element_id,
    ose.description as element_descr,
    ose.suite as elements_suite,
    ose.tag as element_tag,
    ose.parent_id as element_parent_id,
    ose.type_id as element_type_id
    from obs_structure os 
    right join OBS_STRUCTURE_ELEMENT ose
    on os.ID = ose.TYPE_ID
)
start with element_parent_id = (select os.id from obs_structure os where os.structid = 'BDP')
connect by PRIOR element_type_id = element_parent_id
order by element_parent_id, elements_suite;
```

Comment: I think it's because of the `RIGHT JOIN`. Can you change that to `INNER JOIN` to remove the dups?

Comment: Both `obs_structure_element.parent_id` and `obs_structure_element.type_id` = `obs_structure.id`. Is this right?

Comment: @WEI_DBA With `ÌNNER JOIN` I loose all the entries with structure_id/element_type_id = null and I need them because they are the last step of my tree ....

Comment: @APC The foreign key constraints claims that : `OBS_STRUCTURE.ID (STRUCTURE_ID) = OBS_STRUCTURE_ELEMENT.TYPE_ID(ELEMENT_TYPE_ID)` and the `OBS_STRUCTURE_ELEMENT.PARENT_ID (ELEMENT_PARENT_ID)` shows us which STRUCTURE_ID/ELEMENT_TYPE_ID is the parent of the current entry.

Comment: Clearly the problem is somewhere in the joins: you're getting a Cartesian product because you've missed a condition. That's the best you're going to get with the information provided. If you want a more detailed answer you need to post a simplified data model (fewer columns) and some sample data which demonstrates the behaviour.